# Ruby, Rubygem rbconfig missing on Fedora

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm using fedora 20, any idea how I could fix this:

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- rbconfig (LoadError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

This is the output of "gem" and "ruby" commands.

When I run "ruby -v", I got:

```
 ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
```

I already tried to uninstall/reinstall ruby, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, I tried rvm and it fixed it somehow.